# Improve performance on SQL query with select top 1-statement before from-statement

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2012

I have a long complex SQL query (in Microsoft SQL Server 2012) where I need to improve the performance. I have one issue where the SQL query has a 'select top 1' before the from-statement. Hard to explain, so below this text I have wrote an example SQL query with this issue:

```
select 
    Player.Firstname, 
    Player.Lastname,
    LastGameGoals = 
      (select top 1 Goals
       from PlayerSummary 
       where PlayerSummary.PlayerID = Player.PlayerId 
       order by PlayerSummaryId desc)
from Player
```

The SQL above get hockey players firstname and lastname and also number of goals in the last played game for the specific player. Since the database is really large it will get really slow because of the select top 1-statement.

I can of course add an index to get better performance, but can I avoid to do 'select top 1' on every player row?

How can I improve the performance?

Comment: So, why not have the index? Does the query plan really suggest a separate `select top 1` being done for each row? That seems weird.

Comment: There's a defect in SQL server for some `TOP n` queries. See this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143218/select-top-1-harms-query-performance-is-there-a-dba-accessible-way-to-overcome/143221#143221

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this statement:

```
LastGameGoals = 
  (select top 1 Goals
   from PlayerSummary 
   where PlayerSummary.PlayerID = Player.PlayerId 
   order by PlayerSummaryId desc)
```

You want an index.  The best index is `PlayerSummery(PlayerId, PlayerSummaryId, Goals)`.  This is a covering index for the subquery, so it should have a big impact on performance.

I don't see why you would want to avoid the index.  You can rewrite the query using window functions:

```
select p.*,
       ps.goals as LastGameGoals
from player p left join
    (select ps.*,
            row_number() over (partition by playerId order by PlayerSummaryId desc) as seqnum
     from PlayerSummary ps
    ) ps
    on p.playerid = ps.playerid and ps.seqnum = 1;
```

You should test, but my guess is that the index would be faster.

Comment: Why not an index on `PlayerSummary(PlayerId, PlayerSummaryID) INCLUDE(Goals)`? You don't need to look-up on `Goals`, just find it.

Comment: The reason I tried to avoid the index was that I have learned that the 'select'-statements before the 'from'-statement was equal to bad performance. Instead of adding a index I thought it was possible to do some kind of join instead of the select to increase the performance.

But if it is not possible to do it on another way I am satisfied with the answer. :)

Thank you!

Comment: @Delta . . . Let's just say that is a general rule that has many exceptions.  Correlated subqueries do not generate mean bad performance.  Sometimes, they are actually the best way to solve a problem.  If it makes you feel better, you can use `outer apply` instead.  The syntax is almost the same, but the correlated subquery moves to the `from` clause.

Comment: @JonHanna . . . That is another viable way of creating a covering index for the query.